# Center an background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

[image]

Please have a look at the above screen shot, I would want to center an image with black background, but i'm getting some white space at the bottom. Please could any one help me to fix this.

CSS

```
.bgimg {
    background: url('../images/GBS-Chronicle-Background-1.png') black no-repeat center;
}
div#cont {
    height: 672px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="bgimg">
<div id="doc2">
    <div id="hd"></div>
    <div id="bd">
        <div id="cont">
            <div class="middle">
                <p> hi hello </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any white space in the screenshot?

Comment: at the bottom above the status bar of the browser

Comment: I can't reproduce this, are you sure you don't have this white background color somewhere else in your css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
html,body { height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `height:100%;` on your `.bgimg` class.

**Edit:** You may also want to set `padding:0;margin:0;` to your `.bgimg` class as well just to make sure.

Comment: is there white space on the bottom of your background image?

Answer (score 0):

I guess GBS-Chronicle-Background-1.png is not high enough. you can either add background color to black or repeat the image along with Y.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your background rule so the color comes first.

```
background: black url('../images/GBS-Chronicle-Background-1.png') no-repeat center;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this too (as has been suggested above):

body {color:#000000;}

Also: I would suggest commenting out the Height of your content div as well. And/or setting the bkg-color of the content div to the same color as the body. Hope that helps! :)